# Write to tmp folder

Tags: php, linux, rest, command-line, tmp

**EDIT 1**

This question involves the user of the [MANGOPAY API](https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk). My problem is that I cannot get the API to write to the `tmp` folder.

I have succeeded in getting the API to write to `http://fakedomain.com/apifolder/blank.txt` and getting the appropriate output.

I then ran the script `http://fake.com/apifolder/demos/iswrite.php` on `http://fakedomain.com/apifolder/blank.txt` to have minimal working code I could test on the `tmp` folder. Here is the code in the script:

```
<?php

$filename = 'blank.txt';


echo "<br>";


file_exists($filename);

echo "<br>";



if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}

echo "<br>";

if (is_writable($filename)) {
    echo 'The file is writable';
} else {
    echo 'The file is not writable';
}

?>
```

It gives me the output

`The file blank.txt exists
The file is writable`

so all good there. I created the following file with the following permissions using Filezilla:

[image]

In the script `http://fake.com/apifolder/demos/iswrite.php` I have changed the filename variable to `$filename = 'http://fake.com/tmp/creative/blank.txt';`. It gives me the following output:

`The file http://fake.com/tmp/creative/blank.txt does not exist
The file is not writable`

Also, `allow_url_fopen` is on.

I don't fully understand URL structures, so maybe the problem lies there? The tmp folder I am trying to access is on the same level as my `public_html` folder. Maybe I am writing my URLs wrong?

[image]

**Put in another way, does the `tmp` folder have to be outside the `public_html` folder? Would there be any purpose to this? Or can I have create my own `tmp` folder within `public_html` where it is already working?**

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

**The original question was poorly written. Please see EDIT 1**

I am playing with the sandbox of an API ([MangoPay](https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk)). I have included my ClientId and ClientPassword which seems to work.

The API also says...

> You also need to set a folder path in $api->Config->TemporaryFolder
>   that SDK needs to store temporary files. This path should be outside
>   your www folder. It could be /tmp/ or /var/tmp/ or any other location
>   that PHP can write to.

I have created one at:

`ftp://fakedomain@fakedomain/tmp/fakefoldername`

I am running the php script from my desktop using Terminal. The output it is giving me is

> Cannot create or write to file
>   `ftp://fakedomain@fakedomain/tmp/fakefoldername`

even though I have set permissions to 777.

Any idea of why I am getting this error?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm using Linux with CPanel

Comment: Thanks. I added the relevant tag and removed the "http", if that's ok. This could help you get better exposure and related to the OS in question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'll take all the help I can get!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be of help, but see if error reporting (if your system's not already set to catch/display errors/warnings/notices) http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - I'll see what I can find in the meantime Eric.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ftp for the temporary file as part of your testing? Have you tested connecting to the ftp service and creating a file manually?

Comment: Eric, tell us what exactly you put in $api->Config->TemporaryFolder = '/some/path/';

Comment: @RandomSeed **You are 100% correct**. Apologies for that. I have been out of the game for a while, so a bit rusty. The question has now been edited. I hope that brings clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking a temp dir is supposed to be located on the same machine as your code. Using FTP is less than ideal. Are you not able to use a local directory?

You'll notice in the MangoPay documentation it shows a local dir:

https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk

```
$api->Config->TemporaryFolder = '/some/path/';
```

You should probably stick to that, instead of using a remote server via FTP.

Comment: Despite my poor wording, I believe you understood what I was doing wrong here. Would it be possible to check my edit and confirm my suspicions? (see bottom of edit in bold). Thanks!

Comment: To answer your other questions: this `tmp` folder is going to house files that are *not* supposed to be visible from the web (eg, not visible by users in their web browser) since it will contain stuff users are not supposed to be able to access. Putting it along-side the `public_html` folder is fine, but don't expect to be able to access it like this `http://fake.com/tmp/`, since that's not what the tmp folder is for.

Comment: Also, according to their documentation, if you have a sandbox, the `tmp` dir must be different than your non-sandbox site, so make two different `mp` dirs if needed.

Answer (score 5):

I am guessing the library in question is [this one](https://github.com/MangoPay/mangopay2-php-sdk), and the error you are getting is [this exception](https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk/blob/master/MangoPay/Libraries/DefaultStorageStrategy.php#L41):

```
 if (!is_writable($this->GetPathToTemporaryFolder()))
            throw new \MangoPay\Libraries\Exception('Cannot create or write to file ' . $this->GetPathToTemporaryFolder());
```

So basically we seem to be debugging a call to [`is_writable()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).

1. make sure [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) is on
2. if applicable, make sure the [URL includes the FTP password](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php)
3. make sure the folder exists and the FTP account has write permissions (777 should suffice...)

Answer (score 0):

An out-of-the-box Linux machine running Ubuntu 14.04 has the following user and permission settings

```
drwxrwxrwt 13 root root 4096 nov  9 00:56 tmp//
```

And the dummy directory

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 eric eric 4,0K nov  9 00:49 fakefoldername/
```

In case of switching to `777` permission set (as you said, you have already done this), that would be

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 eric eric 4,0K nov  9 00:49 fakefoldername/
```

The point to notice here is that if you used `chmod 777 fakefoldername` it changes the permission set **only** to the directory without touching any of the files/directories in `fakefoldername` (use `chmod -R 777 fakefoldername`). Another point to remember is that directories leading to the `fakefoldername` also need to have sufficient perms. For this particular case, check if `/tmp` folder has them, fix if necessary

```
sudo chmod 1777 tmp/
```

Also, as stated above, I would try to make another directory in `/var` directory and see how things are going then (an nice answer why to or not to choose `/var/tmp` over `/tmp` [here](https://superuser.com/questions/332610/where-is-the-temporary-directory-in-linux)).

For others: the SDK that is used is probably https://github.com/Mangopay/mangopay2-php-sdk

There might be some hints in the somewhat similar answers below:

- http://forum.odin.com/threads/error-message-cant-create-write-to-file-tmp-after-overflow-tmp.296376/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39466/vsftpd-553-could-not-create-file-permissions

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your apache dont have permissions to write that folder, you have to be sure that you are creating that directory with same user (in your case, apache) and also chmod.